# How to Differentiate Between Copies of Sprites

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a function that occurs every 2 seconds which creates an `SKShapeNode`. At any point in time, there are more than one of these sprites on screen. When I call another function, to detect contact between one of these sprites and the main character, the app crashes because the `didBeginContact` function doesn't know which sprite to run on:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        enemy.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1))
        enemy.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(1.5, duration: 1))
        enemy.removeFromParent()
    }
```

Sprites being created:

```
func Enemy(){
let enemy = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
self.addChild(enemy)
enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), duration: 2.0))
    }
```

Is there anyway to differentiate between the copies in Swift, such as a unique key which can be called for each?

Comment: Use userData to give each copy a unique identification.

Comment: Some observations....1) `enemy` in the `Enemy` method is a local variable (with limited scope). I suspect that `enemy` in `didBeginContact` is uninitialized or referencing a different object, 2) you will need to add a physics body to the nodes to trigger a contact, 3) you should create a sequence/group to fade/scale/removeFromParent because a node needs to be in the scene (or node tree) to run an action. You are removing the node from its parent before the actions have a chance to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contact.bodyA.node` is either the main character or the colliding sprite. `contact.bodyB.node` is the other.

Make a subclass for enemies:

```
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode { }
```

Use it:

```
func addEnemy(){
    let enemy = Enemy(circleOfRadius: 15)
    self.addChild(enemy)
    enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), duration: 2.0))
}
```

Check for it:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if let enemy = contact.bodyA.node as? Enemy {
        removeEnemy(enemy)
    } else if let enemy = contact.bodyB.node as? Enemy {
        removeEnemy(enemy)
    }
}

func removeEnemy(enemy: Enemy) {
    enemy.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1))
    enemy.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(1.5, duration: 1))
    enemy.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: I am afraid your approach is pointless.  If you ran it, all enemy node copies would be removed.

Comment: Really? By setting the `collisionBitMask` and `categoryBitMask` properties appropriately on the nodes, vblaga can ensure that `didBeginContact` will only be called for collisions between an enemy and the player, so each call will remove exactly one enemy that is in collision with the player.

Answer (score 0):

Make an Enemy subclass:

```
class Enemy: SKShapeNode { }
```

With a property to store an ID:

```
var ID: String?
```

Set the ID during enemy creating:

```
func Enemy(){
    let enemy = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
    enemy.ID = a unique ID
    self.addChild(enemy)
    enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), duration: 2.0))
}
```

Check the enemy ID in

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {    
  if let enemy = contact.bodyA.node as? Enemy {
    if enemy.ID = ...
  } else if let enemy = contact.bodyB.node as? Enemy {
    if enemy.ID = ...
  }
```